# Excel. Data Bar Fill background Part of bar

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, conditional-formatting

Is there a way to in Excel 2016 to fill the background part of a data bar. not the progress bit the other part so for 25% 1/4 will be red and the other 3/4 will be green.

OR is there a way to make the bar part fill to the edges of the cell so i can then just use a normal fill of green and have the data bar red

Thanks

Comment: Making perfect color combination is tedious job, you can use Range("A2").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 250) command but it needs lots of hard work.

Comment: And cell border can be created easily using conditional formatting .

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, the problem is that the data bar doesn't quite fill the full height of the cell.  In your example, you can see the green background above and below the red bar.

You should be able to fix this by adding a thick border between the cells.  The border should cover over the unwanted part of the background.  Use the normal Format Cells/Border menu, not the border option in the data bar setup.  Colour the border white (or the background colour of your spreadsheet), to make it less obtrusive